# SwiftUI DatePicker not translating titleKey

Tags: swiftui

In the below code the `Text` contents are translated, but the `DatePicker` title is not. Both keys exist inside the localization file.

Any idea why this happens?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    private let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let now = Date()
        let past = calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 1), to: calendar.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -1), to: now)!)!
        
        return past
            ...
            now
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
            Form {
                    Text("estimated_monthly_price")
                    DatePicker("purchase_date", selection: $viewModel.purchaseDate, in: dateRange, displayedComponents: [.date])
                }
    }
}
```

this is in Xcode 12.4

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with `NSLocalizedString("purchase_date", comment: "")`. Sometimes you need to specify it when the string isn't in a Text view.

Answer (score 1):

If you check `DataPicker` initialiser its `titleKey` parameter accepts type as `LocalizedStringKey`. So try passing it as `LocalizedStringKey("purchase_date”)` in `DataPicker`.

```
public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, selection: Binding<Date>, in range: PartialRangeThrough<Date>, displayedComponents: DatePicker<Label>.Components = [.hourAndMinute, .date])
```